# Is there an Eclipse plugin for generating design patterns

Tags: java, eclipse, design-patterns, eclipse-plugin

Is there a  wizard like plugin for Eclipse  that can generate all design patterns in Java and/or in C++, and it is free to use? I want something like [this](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/codepro/doc/features/patterns/pattern_wizard)

I want to make a plugin as my diplomawork, PatternBox, and CodePro I already found.
PatternBox is not full, and CodePro as i understood is a part of a software package.

Comment: @Ali
I meant something like this:
https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/codepro/doc/features/patterns/pattern_wizard

Comment: @GáborCsikós Interesting. Please add this piece of information to your question, together with the link. I will retract my close vote. Good luck with your Master's Thesis!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the [Eclipse plugin from Patternbox](http://www.patternbox.com/projekte/eclipse-plugin.html) is what you are searching for.

Caveat: I have never used it and won't try it out, I don't think is the right idea ...

Comment: I already found this, and updated my question.